# Embed web link in WMV file

Tags: hyperlink, wmv

I was wondering if there is any way to make part of a WMV file clickable, linking to a web site.
A client is sponsoring a set of video lectures and they get a short spot at the beginning. I was wondering if I could embed a link within the video, or overlay the video with a link.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No. If this video must be on webpage, then use Flash-based video player like JWPlayer or FlowPlayer and make there clickable overlay.